# Wrong playlist is playing when musicPlayer uses setQueueWithItemCollection:playlist

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitemcollection

I am trying to load a playlist from my iTunes library using the following code. The code works for all playlist names except for the one called "Christmas & pop mix" (other playlist names also have an & in the name). For "Christmas & pop mix", the music player is getting loaded with the playlist called "3, 4, & 5 Star Music". Note that the playlist "Christmas & pop mix" is being found within the for loop below. But the actual collection that plays is the wrong one. Any ideas how I might track this problem down?

```
        NSString *nameOfPlaylistToPlay = @"Christmas & pop mix";
        // Get a collection of all playlists on the device
        MPMediaQuery *playlistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
        NSArray *localPlaylists = [playlistsQuery collections];

        // Check each playlist to see if it is the right one
        for (MPMediaItemCollection *playlist in localPlaylists) {
            NSString *playlistName = [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName];
            if ([playlistName isEqualToString:nameOfPlaylistToPlay]) {
                // Add the playlist to the player's queue and get out of here
                [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:playlist];
                playlistFound = YES;
                break;
            }
        }

        [musicPlayer play];
```

Comment: This isn't the best way to fetch songs from a playlist since `MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName` is not unique (what if you have two playlists with the same name?). Better to use `MPMediaPlaylistPropertyPersistentID`.

Comment: Also, try outputting the title of the playlist `playlistName` inside your `if` and see what it reads. Possibly replace `for (MPMediaItemCollection *playlist in localPlaylists)` with `for (MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in localPlaylists)` too.

Comment: That is the way I originally had it before I posted this question. It did not work either. Its such a mystery

Comment: Did you `NSLog` the `playlistName` variable before setting the queue? What was the title?

Comment: yes, playlistName looks to be identical to nameOfPlaylistToPlay. Specifically, it is "Christmas & pop mix" without the quotes